# Use a handlebars helper within a partial tag

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a handlebars helper which allows me to translate strings into their supported locales:

`{{getString "my-translatable-string"}}`

```
function getString(id, args) {
  const supportedLocales = getSupportedLocales(args);
  return LocaleUtils.fluentFormat(supportedLocales, id, args.hash);
}
```

I want to pass that value to a handlebars partial

`{{> mypartial alt="{{getString "my-translatable-string"}}"}}`

but this throws errors. How do I pass/interpolate the result of "getString" into the alt parameter of the partial tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two issues:

First, by wrapping the value of `alt` in quotes it looks like we are trying to pass a literal string as the value of the `alt` parameter to our partial. However, we want to use a Handlebars expression, so those quotes should be removed.

Second, Handlebars will not allow us to nest mustaches. Instead, Handlebars will allow us to use [subexpressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions) by wrapping the subexpression in parentheses.

The resulting template becomes:

```
{{> mypartial alt=(getString "my-translatable-string")}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/t9ocyLj2/) for your reference.